# Can't access a reference to a new mail window in Outlook 2010

Tags: c#-4.0, vsto, intellisense, office-interop, outlook-addin

I'm building my first plug-in to Outlook and according to the code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), I'm supposed to add the following code to the event handler.

```
new Microsoft.Office.Interop
  .Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(foo);
```

As i type it in, the syntax works (no red underscores) and the code compiles. **However**, for some reason, the intellisense doesn't present me with *that* particular option, meaning I have to type it all by myself. That makes me sad.

Even worse, as I execute the project, the listener event is fired **but** the line below doesn't result in an object - `mailItem` remains `null`.

```
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = inspector as Outlook.MailItem;
```

1. Why is there no intellisense for `.Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(foo);`?
2. Can I enable it somehow and if so how?
3. How can I access the newly created message frame?

My bet is that it's got to do with `Interop` reference and I suspect that it actually doesn't work since the `Count` field in `inspectors` equals to zero both *before* and *after* the handler adding operation.

Execution of the line below only returns `null`, instead of an instance of `MailItem`, despite the fact that a new mail window opens (with no changes to it, of course). While the input parameter `inspector` differs from `null`, the as-'ification seems to nullify it.

I run VS10/.NET4.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Inspector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869356.aspx) represents the window that contains the [Outlook item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866278.aspx). To access the item contained in the window, you need to use [`Inspector.CurrentItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869722.aspx):

```cs
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
```

For the intellisense issue, try this using statement:

```cs
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
inspectors.NewInspector += new Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(foo);
```

Comment: I'll try that in a while. However, the code I've used is taken directly from MS's site so I surprised that it's wrong... Or maybe I've done something less intelligent. :) Thanks friend!

Comment: Please accept this answer if it helped you so that others may benefit, otherwise let us know what worked or didn't work.